# (a)Smack: TLS socket is closed when trying to login with XMPP

Tags: android, ssl, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying to connect with asmack (Android Gingerbread) to google talk. I have set `connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("BKS")` - so I get over the certificates problem. Now the failure is in the `XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived()` function, that is called after the server sent 'proceed' for the 'starttls' request.

This function is supposed to initialize the TSL socket. It fails with an exception "java.net.SocketException: Socket closed".

```
// Verify certificate presented by the server
context.init(kms,
    new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[]{new ServerTrustManager(getServiceName(), config)},
    //new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[]{new OpenTrustManager()},
    new java.security.SecureRandom());
Socket plain = socket;
// Secure the plain connection
socket = context.getSocketFactory().createSocket(plain, plain.getInetAddress().getHostName(), plain.getPort(), false);
socket.setSoTimeout(0); ////// THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
```

Any clues?

The socket is described as:
SSL socket over Socket[addr=talk.google.com/173.194.70.125,port=5222,localport=34840]

It fails on the emulator, and on my Galaxy S I9000.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there was a timeout issue with the SSL connection. It took my application so much time to generate the SSL socket (over the plain socket) that the other side simply gave up... This, or there was a key problem (but I did not receive any authentication errors).

I resolved the problem by:

1. Moving to API level 15 - that uses AndroidCSStore, and not BKS (which I used for API 10).
2. Get password using [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) - it is actually a token, but it is later used as a password when connecting.
3. I do not have spare time to really get to the bottom of the problem. It now works, and that's all that matters.

I posted my code below. SASLXOAuth2Mechanism is complete. But the code from Main is methodical, not complete. I ripped pieces of code from other answers on this site, I apologize in advance for my plagiary.

**Main.java - initiate asmack**

```
// Init asmack, and register new mechanisms.
asmack = SmackAndroid.init(ctx);

SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", SASLXOAuth2Mechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", 0);

ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = 
    new ConnectionConfiguration (getHost(), getPort(), getService());
connectionConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
connectionConfig.setSecurityMode(true);
connectionConfig.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
connectionConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
connectionConfig.setSendPresence(false);
//connectionConfig.setCompressionEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePassword(null);
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePath(null);
} /*else {
        connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("BKS");
        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        if (path == null)
            path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                + "cacerts.bks";
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePath(path);
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
 //} */

 XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfig);
```

**SASLXOAuth2Mechanism.java - the XOAuth2 mechanism**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import de.measite.smack.Sasl;

public class SASLXOAuth2Mechanism extends SASLMechanism
{
    static final String AUTHENTICATOR_URL = "http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth";
    protected String authenticationText = null;
    static final String TAG = "SASLXOAuth2Mechanism";

    public SASLXOAuth2Mechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName()
    {
        return "X-OAUTH2";
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, String password) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        this.password = password;
        this.authenticationId = username;

        StringBuilder credentials = new StringBuilder();
        credentials.append("\0");
        credentials.append(username);
        credentials.append("\0");
        credentials.append(password);
        authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(credentials.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);

        String[] mechanisms = { "PLAIN" };
        Map<String,String> props = new HashMap<String,String>();
        sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, username, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new XOAuth2AuthMechanism(getName(), authenticationText));
    }

    /**
     * Initiating SASL authentication by select a mechanism.
     */
    public class XOAuth2AuthMechanism extends Packet {
        final private String name;
        final private String authenticationText;

        public XOAuth2AuthMechanism(String name, String authenticationText) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.authenticationText = authenticationText;
        }

        public String toXML() {
            StringBuilder stanza = new StringBuilder();
            stanza.append("<auth mechanism=\"").append(name);
            stanza.append("\" xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\" auth:service=\"oauth2\" xmlns:auth=\"").append(AUTHENTICATOR_URL);
            stanza.append("\">");
            if (authenticationText != null) {
                stanza.append(authenticationText);
            }
            stanza.append("</auth>");
            return stanza.toString();
        }
    }
}
```